# array with javascript won't use list correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have code here and I'm wondering why if inputed let's say 400 or 700... it won't go to those particular places. It just goes to range of  $200 - $299.

I couldn't find the error.. Please help out
.............

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>10.10</title>

    <style type = "text/css">

         table, table td   { padding: 5px }

    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var counters = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ];
        function submitSales()
        {   
            var salary = 0;
            var grossSales = parseInt( document.getElementById( "grossField" ).value );
            if ( isNaN( grossSales ) )
            {
                window.alert( "Invalid gross entered!" );
                return;
            }
            salary = 200 + parseInt( ( .09 * grossSales ) );
            if ( salary >= 200 && salary <= 299 )
                ++counters[ 0 ];
            if ( salary >= 300 && salary <= 399 )
                ++counters[ 1 ];
            if ( salary >= 400 && salary <= 499 )
                ++counters[ 2 ];
            if ( salary >= 500 && salary <= 599 )
                ++counters[ 3 ];
            if ( salary >= 600 && salary <= 699 )
                ++counters[ 4 ];
            if ( salary >= 700 && salary <= 799 )
                ++counters[ 5 ];
            if ( salary >= 800 && salary <= 899 )
                ++counters[ 6 ];
            if ( salary >= 900 && salary <= 999 )
                ++counters[ 7 ];
            if ( salary >= 1000 )
                ++counters[ 8 ];
            displayResults();
            document.getElementById( "grossField" ).value = "0";
        }
        function displayResults()
        {   
            var printoutTable = "<table border = \"1\">";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td colspan = \"2\" style = \"text-align: center\"><h1>Weekly Salary Range Report</h1></td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>Range</td><td>Number of Employees</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$200-299</td><td>" + counters[ 0 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$300-399</td><td>" + counters[ 1 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$400-499</td><td>" + counters[ 2 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$500-599</td><td>" + counters[ 3 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$600-699</td><td>" + counters[ 4 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$700-799</td><td>" + counters[ 5 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$800-899</td><td>" + counters[ 6 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$900-999</td><td>" + counters[ 7 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "<tr><td>$1000+</td><td>" + counters[ 8 ] + "</td></tr>";
            printoutTable += "</table>";
            document.getElementById( "salesPrintout" ).innerHTML = printoutTable;

        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <form action = "">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan = "2" style = "text-align: center"><h1>Employee Gross Sales:</h1></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gross Sales: </td>
                <td>$<input id = "grossField" type = "text" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td />
                <td><input type = "button" value = "Submit Sales"
                    onclick = "submitSales()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id = "salesPrintout">
            <table border = "1">
                <tr><td colspan = "2" style = "text-align: center"><h1>Weekly Salary Range Report</h1></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Range</td><td>Number of Employees</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$200-299</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$300-399</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$400-499</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$500-599</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$600-699</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$700-799</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$800-899</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$900-999</td><td>0</td></tr>
                <tr><td>$1000+</td><td>0</td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If he inputs `400`, You set `salary = 200 + 0.09 * 400` which is `236`, so it's still in the `200-299` range. If he inputs `700`, `salary` is `263`.

Comment: You programmer works fine, you place wrong calculates

Comment: You don't get out of the `200-299` range unless you enter at least `1112` as the salary.

Comment: BTW, you should use `else if` instead of `if`, since all the cases are mutually exclusive.

Comment: wow I see now haha